# Geometric progresssion and recursive relation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. But I was reading about geometric progression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) and I don't understand how the highlighted part is true:

[image]

I assume the sequence starts at 1 since $a_1 = ar^0$. But if we apply this assumption to the second, wouldn't it be $a_1 = ra_0$? Why is $n$ allowed to be equal to $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you're right. That article is a casualty in the war between $0$ and $1$ (see [zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)). At one time, the section read $a_n=ar^{n-1}$ and $n\geq2$, which makes sense if the first value of $n$ is $1$.

Then it was changed to $a_n=ar^n$ and $n\geq1$ with [this edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Geometric_progression&diff=201181264&oldid=201177287), which makes sense if the first value of $n$ is $0$.

Then it was partially changed back to $a_n=ar^{n-1}$ and $n\geq1$ with [these edits](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Geometric_progression&diff=202431307&oldid=201435439). Now it doesn't make sense for any convention on $n$. Apparently, in the four years since, you're the first person to take notice! Feel free to edit the article and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a slight mistake there. The equations differ by a factor $r$ if you expand with $n\ge1$ and $a_0 = a$.

In general, a recursive relation is defined for $n \ge 1$ with the case $n=0$ fixed as the basis. Other recursive relations  might be generally defined for $n \ge 2$, such as the fibonnaci sequence, because you need to have the cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ fixed.